# how to mod rewrite in actual domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

sorry if this is a duplicate but pretty confusing reading all others post..

This is for laravel4 framework

I know that when offline we can use mod rewrite with virtual host to make directory such as
`c:/laravel4/public` and `c:/laravel4/public/posts`

into
`www.l4.com` and `www.l4.com/posts` which runs on browsers

but when I'm hosting it upon real domain how can I change something like 
`sample.com/laravel4/public/posts`
into
`sample.com/posts`

Thanks in advance for any help~!

Edit:
Sorry I didn't mention my OS it's windows in my local computer but in my domain account it says OS is Linux with php5.3

My original .htaccess which is under the public folder has such code in it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `how can I change something like sample.com/laravel4/public/posts into sample.com/posts`

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^laravel4/public/ /laravel4/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

If you want URL as: `www.mydomain.com/laravel4/posts` then place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^laravel4/((?!public/).*)$ /laravel4/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: ok the original url is www.mydomain.com/laravel4/public/posts by using the laravel4 framework and the .htaccess file is in the public folder and I edited my post there are some codes inside the .htaccess already and so right under the `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` I put your `RewriteRule !^laravel4/public/ /laravel4/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]` code in then try if www.mydomain.com/posts works but didn't

Comment: then I thought by DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess I thought it's the laravel4 folder so I created one .htaccess file in the laravel4 folder and since there weren't any .htaccess file inside the laravel4 folder so after I created the .htaccess file I added in your code `RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^laravel4/public/ /laravel4/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]` but still didn't work >.<"

Comment: **It should be placed in the parent directory** of `laravel4`. And you need to access your URL as `http://www.mydomain.com/posts`

Comment: thanks a lot!~~!~
just got one more question if I want it to be www.mydomain.com/laravel4/posts I just change the `RewriteRule !^laravel4/public/ /laravel4/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]`
to `RewriteRule !^laravel4/ /laravel4/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]`

Comment: not sure if you'll see this but with the second question the `www.mydomain.com/laravel4/posts` I used your code and placed at the document_root but I do get an `Internal Server Error`

Comment: I always try to respond to any comment. May I request you to create a new question with this problem since SO admins may not like new question/answer sessions in long comment.

Comment: thanks a lot I just posted it at.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060471/how-to-modify-this-mod-rewrite-into-the-url-i-want

Comment: I posted an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

When using Laravel, you should point Apache to your public folder as the location from where it serves the site, not the root of Laravel.

Comment: I believe I get what you mean but that's only for localhost and using virtual host which is for it to work clean url on your computer isn't it?
But I meant if I'm hosting in an active domain how can I shorten/clean the url?
Sorry if I'm wrong I'm quite new with the mod rewrite

Comment: No problem. You don't need mod rewrite for this (but it's good to hide "index.php" from your URL), you just need to set your document root to your Laravel's public folder. For example, if your Laravel is on a Windows server at c:\laravel4, you have to set your Apache document root to c:\laravel4\public, and then restart Apache.

If you're trying to have the webserver do something in the posts folder, you should write a Route to handle that. I'm assuming your posts directory just has loose files in it you want to serve?

Comment: I'm talking about having a clean url in an active domain not in a domestic computer though which I thought shouldn't involve apache isn't it?

Comment: let's say I own a domain called www.sample.com and then I uploaded the whole laravel folder into the domain BUT in the domain I need to type www.sample.com/laravel4/public/posts in order to work but I want to rewrite *not sure if it's called rewrite here* so if you type www.sample.com/posts the page will load up

Comment: really sorry for my bad english if there's some misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable mod rewrite as the previous fellow said and I am going to assume you are using linux (ubuntu) since you didn't specify your OS. You can enable mod_rewrite by typing this in the terminal.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Once that is done go to

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

assuming you are using apache and a linux (ubuntu) server. The look for your domains site, or in case you are using  the default host, open it up with your favourite text editor and change this line to point to your public directory

```
DocumentRoot /path-to-your-folder/public

eg DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/public
```

Save the file and restart apache with the command;

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You should be good to go without typing public in your url.

Thus `www.l4.com/public/posts` will now become `www.l4.com/posts`

Comment: I suppose this is for local usage instead of setting up an actual active domain?