# how to modify this mod rewrite into the url I want?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I actually got an answer that if I want to change my url from `www.mydomain.com/laravel4/public/posts` into `www.mydomain.com/posts`

this is what I have to do with my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^laravel4/public/ /laravel4/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

but I have another question if I want the url to be `www.mydomain.com/laravel4/posts` which takes out the public what should I modify? I thought taking out the laravel4 in the code above would work but doesn't seem that easy :(

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should move the Laravel install out of the document root and just move the contents of the public folder into your document root and edit the index.php and bootstrap/paths.php accordingly, or alternatively set the document root to the public folder of Laravel, some hosts will change the document root for you if you open a support ticket.

However thats not always possible depending on your host, and most people will tell you to go off and find a better host, but again, thats not always an option.

Below is a .htaccess example you can use to rewrite all URLs to the public/index.php of Laravel, but be warned, this isn't a very secure way to setup Laravel, and anyone could potentially access any of your configuration and other files that exist in your document root, exposing your database passwords and secret keys used to encryption.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ laravel4/public/index.php [L]
```

Updated as per request

```
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteRule ^laravel4/.* laravel4/public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: ah, I believe I get what you mean.  But doesn't people need the domain password in order to open up configuration and stuff?
by the way, the rewriterule helps taking out the laravel4/public/index.php but I'm wondering if I just want to take out the public/index.php and keep laravel4/posts or laravel4/something

Comment: Anything you put in the document root can be accessed by anyone who knows the site URL. I mean you can use htpassword and stuff like that but its still potentially accessible if theres a misconfiguration somewhere. Its just safer to move it completely out of the document root where theres no way to access it unless you have some sort of access to the server itself. See my updated answer to keep laravel4 in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravel4/public(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^laravel4/(.*)$ /laravel4/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? And is there any .htaccess in laravel directory?

Comment: location above .htaccess is nothing...it's already at the root of the domain which is and in the laravel directory there's a public folder and inside that public folder there's a `.htaccess` file.  I tried deleting that `.htaccess` file but still doesn't work too

Comment: So what is happening when you enter `http://www.mydomain.com/laravel4/posts`? Is it 404? What is exact error message in your browser> Is this .htaccess at same level as `laravel` directory? Is there any .htaccess in `/laravel/` as well?